# Migrate ResultSet between two MySQL tables without specifying columns in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, migration

I have a MySQL database on server #1 and I need to migrate it to server #2. The database is very large and methods like mysqldump or MySQL Workbench Migration didn't work for me, so I wanted to write my own Java application, that would perform the following steps:

1. get all table names from the source database schema
2. for each table, it would select a batch of records (let's say 10.000 at a time) and insert them in the corresponding table in destination database. The schema is already prepared with correctly defined tables.
3. repeat until there are no rows left for current table.
4. repeat for each table.

The problem is, AFAIK, when using JDBC, it is needed to iterate through ResultSet and specify all column types and names, like this:

```
while (resultset.next()) {                      
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 1"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 2"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 3"));                    
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col n"));
}
```

I want to do this for all tables and all their columns without specifying their names and types **manually**. I can't just type manually all these columns, as I have 150 tables and each of them has like 10-50 columns.

Is there any general way how to do this? Maybe taking advantage of the fact that both source and destination schemas are the same (same tables with same column names/types and same foreign keys)?

Comment: Whats wrong with *mysqldump*? On *very large* databases you typically want to use *utilities* and not *row by row* migration...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ResultSetMetaData` with `ResultSet` to get the columnNames, columnCount and few other details.

```
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();  
ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
    }
}
```

if you need to fetch the type of Column also to make the decision you could use `Switch` conditions based on the type returned from `resultSetMetaData.getColumnTypeName(i)` for using something like

- `resultSet.getString()`
- `resultSet.getInt()`
- `resultSet.getBoolean()`
- `resultSet.getDate()`
- Many more

Comment: And to get the list of tables, you can use `conn.getMetaData()`.

Answer (score 1):

On top of @koushlendra answer, you can also use these methods for additional informations(if needed)

1. `resultSetMetaData.getTableName(int column)`    Returns the column’s table name.
2. `resultSetMetaData.getSchemaName(int column)` Returns the name of the schema of the column’s table.